# Using RouteLink with Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

In my MVC application I have a default route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new []{ "Demo.Controllers" }
);
```

I created a new Area called Admin and it added a route to in the AdminAreaRegistration class:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In my main _Layout file I tried to do the following:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Admin", "Admin_default")
```

It only works in certain cases (such as if I'm already in an Admin page). If I am in the /Home/About section of my site, then the URL gets generated like so:

```
/Admin/Home/About
```

If I am in my Index action of the Home controller (in the main area, not admin) then the URL gets generated like so:

```
/Admin
```

Why doesn't RouteLink work like I think it should using Areas in MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.RouteLink("Admin", "Admin_default")` this route uses the route with the name of `Admin_default` so it will always use that route to generate the url.

`@Html.RouteLink("Admin", "Admin_default", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" })`

When you don't specify stuff like route values most of MVC uses the values that currently exist. In this case since the `action` and `controller` values are null it looks at the `RouteValues` and checks to see if they're there and if they're found they use the values found there instead.

This is sometimes helpful. For instance if you want `{id}` to be populated with the same value that was used on the page.

Url: `/home/edit/1701`

`@Html.RouteLink("Refresh", "Default")` would result in the same exact url - you can specify overrides if you want.

Comment: I'm expecting the URL to be `/Admin`. My defaults for the Admin_default route are: controller = "Home", action = "Index". Why would it use About as my action?

Comment: Ah, in that case it's using the existing route values that are in the request - updating answer

Comment: So why does it use the current route values that are in the page? That seems odd to me.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest not naming your routes. You can force yourself to do this by passing null to the route name arg when creating it.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(null,
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

You can then use RouteLink like so:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Admin", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Admin" })
```

**Reply to comment**

Wish I could say I came up with the idea. Learned this from Steve Sanderson's MVC book. There are a ton of method overloads that take a route name as a parameter (RouteLink, but also RedirectToRoute and others). Not using route names forces you to use other overloads of those methods, which IMO are more intuitive and easier to "get right".

Comment: I had no idea you could do this...I figured since route names had to be unique that they were required. Mind = blown

Answer (score 1):

Naming your routes is not recommended since it creates dependencies in your view towards the existing routes. I suggest using a null value

Comment: The problem with relying on route names to generate outgoing URLs is that doing so breaks through the
separation of concerns that is so central to the MVC design pattern. When generating a link or a URL in a
view or action method, we want to focus on the action and controller that the user will be directed to, not
the format of the URL that will be used. By bringing knowledge of the different routes into the views or
controllers, we are creating dependencies that we would prefer to avoid. (specifiy null as the name and use comments in your code)  (Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC3)